# why internal func name in decorator display?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code is as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def use_logging(func):
  def _deco():
    print("%s is running" % func.__name__)
    func()
  return _deco

@use_logging
def bar():
  print('i am bar')
```

when I execute `bar()` , the output is

```
bar is running
i am bar
```

when I execute `use_logging(bar)()` , the output has `_deco is running`.

output:

```
_deco is running
bar is running
i am bar
```

I want to know why `_deco is running` is showing when executing `use_logging(bar)()` , and how does it work?

Additional,I add `print ("hhhhhhh")` before `def _deco():`, the code is as follows:

```
def use_logging(func):
  print ("hhhhhhh")
  def _deco():
    print ("_deco func")
    print("%s is running" % func.__name__)
    func()
  return _deco

@use_logging
def bar():
  print('i am bar')
```

when I execute `use_logging(bar)()` again, the output is:

```
hhhhhhh
hhhhhhh
_deco func
_deco is running
_deco func
bar is running
i am bar
```

The `first two lines` are all "hhhhhhh" , can you tell me the reason why `the second` "hhhhhhh" is showing?

Comment: Answers your question: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#who-are-you-really

Comment: If you want to keep the original function name, just do `_deco.__name__ = func.__name__` before you return it

Comment: The first line of `hhhhhhh` comes from when you decorate `def bar` with `@use_logging`. Otherwise, just `use_logging(bar)()` prints a single line of `hhhhhhh`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you do:

```
use_logging(bar)()
```

After you do:

```
@use_logging
def bar():
  print('i am bar')
```

You are decorating the function returned from your decorator on the previous invocation. That is syntactic sugar for:

```
bar = use_logging(bar)
```

And logging returned the internally defined `_deco` function. Note, if you:

```
print(bar)
```

You get:

```
<function use_logging.<locals>._deco at 0x7fa2c50473a0>
```

Comment: I add `print ("hhhhhhh")` before `def _deco():`, and execute `use_logging(bar)() ` again, and `the first two lines` are all  "hhhhhhh" , can you tell me the reason why the `second`  "hhhhhhh" is showing?

Comment: @xoyabc I don't understand what you mean, please *edit your question* and provide an exact, reproducible example of what you are doing

Comment: Added in the Additional part,and thanks in advance.

Comment: is `use_logging(bar)()` equal to `use_logging(use_loging(bar))()`?

Comment: @xoyabc no. no it isn't, not in general.

Comment: `func` is `bar` at first, then execute `use_loging(bar)` parameter in the bracket and `_deco` returns, then execute the `external use_logging` ,`func` becomes to `_deco`and a new `_deco` returns.At last,execute the new return `_deco()`,and `_deco is running` is showing first,then execute `func()`,it is `_deco()` now, `_deco()` is the function returned first time, whose func para and name is all `bar`,then `bar is running
i am bar` is showing? Is right?